# What are the specifics of 18.04's ten year support?

Tags: 18.04, lts, canonical

Apparently Shuttleworth announced at the [OpenStack Summit that Ubuntu 18.04 will have ten years of support](https://blog.ubuntu.com/2018/11/15/openstack-summit-berlin-mark-shuttleworth) ([originally cited ZDnet article](https://www.zdnet.com/article/mark-shuttleworth-reveals-ubuntu-18-04-will-get-a-10-year-support-lifespan/)). But neither the [Ubuntu website](https://www.ubuntu.com/about/release-cycle) nor [the Ubuntu wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases) have been updated to reflect that.

What exactly is included in this ten-year support?

---

I'm not looking for speculation or guesses or indications. I'm looking for verifiable, official information.

Comment: Consider to add link to [the official Ubuntu blog](https://blog.ubuntu.com/2018/11/15/openstack-summit-berlin-mark-shuttleworth) (search for "10 years" and cite this part).

Comment: Meh. All that has is the same quote shown everywhere else, buried deep down.

Comment: Looks like it was announced yesterday. Canonical isn't Apple, so I doubt they're able to update documentation as quickly as a large consumer brand like that.

Comment: But once would expect a decision with a 10 year impact being thoroughly documented before the announcement, so all you need to do is actually post the documentation. Unless Shuttleworth did it on the spur of the moment, ... which wouldn't inspire confidence.

Comment: Ubuntu 18.04 LTS currently has five years of free support.  At the end of those years you can extend it to ESM (paid contract) for additional years.  12.04 ESM had an additional three years initially (5+3=8) so Mark is just saying Ubuntu 18.04 will have 5 years as LTS & 5 years as ESM (2 years extra that 12.04 LTS/ESM had)  *He's removing the marketing-plus RedHat had with it's 10 year life of RHEL/CentOS.. in my opinion*

Comment: I reported [bug 1803786 against `ubuntu-support-status`](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/update-manager/+bug/1803786) as an attempt to get official position about 10 years EOL for Ubuntu 18.04 LTS.

Comment: Logically he's just announcing  to industry early (3 yrs.) that 18.04 will get the ESM option. Looking at 14.04 ESM was announced about 9 months prior to availability.

Comment: See the video by yourself and make your own conclusions.
https://youtu.be/V10cgn_avJE?t=406

Comment: Those 10 years is part of the "Ubuntu advantage" support plan. If you want it: it costs 150 euro a year with a minimum of 50 desktops. The extended support for 12.04 is 8 year (april 2020) and that will be extended to 10 years for 18.04.

Answer (score 10):

The [Releases](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases) page has some clear dates for how long security support will last.

For 18.04, it's 5 years of standard security support + 5 years of ESM (ESM = "[Extended Security Maintenance](https://www.ubuntu.com/esm)").

- 2019-03-04 - first public list for 14.04 ESM.
- 2017-04-13 - first public list for 12.04 ESM.

We (Canonical) do need to improve on publishing the ESM source package list more in advance.

From either list on the Releases page you can see what packages were included in previous releases to get a general idea.  Desktop packages are not being considered.

I'll update this answer as we publish more.

Comment: You've not directly stated so, but it probably could be beneficial to explicitly mention that it's 5 years support + 5 years ESM ( and maybe clarify what that is for those who don't know ). There's confirmations of that in [launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/update-manager/+bug/1803786?_ga=2.111864256.578976829.1544746410-1174000787.1540064934) and [Ubuntu IRC](https://irclogs.ubuntu.com/2018/11/16/%23ubuntu-release.html#t19:24) channel which the launchpad bug also cited

Comment: Added per suggestion