# What happens to Ubuntu 18.04 after 2023?

Tags: 18.04

I am using Ubuntu 18.04 LTS, Ubuntu will stop all supports in 2023.1. can I use 18.04 after 2023?2. Ubuntu will give an upgrade and I have to do this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are the specifics of 18.04's ten year support?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1093582/what-are-the-specifics-of-18-04s-ten-year-support) and [What's the difference between a Long Term Support Release and a Normal Release?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/16366/) It's your computer and you can do whatever you want with it including running an unsupported Ubuntu release.

Comment: You can use it just fine. Canonical simply won't provide security updates after that 10 year period. If you're a desktop user - to you that means very little. You can still use the OS just fine for browsing internet or writing documents. To enterprise level customers, big organizations - 10 years of security support is great news, it costs less to upgrade big infrastructure to newer OS, but they still will have to upgrade. In the enterprise environment security is a big deal.

Comment: @SergiyKolodyazhnyy I would argue that security updates are **more** important on the desktop than elsewhere. In an commercial setting I could mitigate a lot of risks via external components, which is less viable on a desktop...

Comment: @vidarlo It's a can of worms I wouldn't want to open as a discussion. Security is important everywhere, but organizations have password hashes, personal information, credit card information and other records on many individuals. Once a security vulnerability comes out, there's more interest in big organizations than in average home desktop users.

Comment: @SergiyKolodyazhnyy I agree that the target value is higher, but the exposed surface of a browser running anything a website hands it is rather large, and difficult to mitigate. So not running old software is a good advise on desktop as well :)

Comment: @vidarlo Yes, agreed - it's a good advise on desktop as well.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use it, all will work as before.

If you stay on 18.04, you will stop receiving updates after 2023. But there will be two more LTS versions in the meantime with five year support, 20.04 and 22.04 and you can upgrade to them without reinstall. That will extend support window accordingly.